# How to call a Struct of variable or constant to include to Dictionary in Alamofire Get Request

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I am new in using Swift I created an APIService using Alamofire, I tried to check whether I can retrieve data from API and it turn out well. My problem now, how can the data reflect to the variables in my **Event Struct**, so I could perform some validation base on the data read. I tried to check thru breakpoint but variable can't read data or either " " value. Please help me. Thank you

**Event Struct**

```
struct Event: Codable {

let id: String?
let name: String
let location: String
let startDateTime: Date
let endDateTime: String
let deleteFlag: Bool?
let deleteDateTime: String?
let dateCreated: String?
let hasRaffle: Bool?
let registrationReq: Bool?
let participantCount: Int
let closedFlag: Bool?
let closedDateTime: String?
let reopenFlag: Bool?
let reopenDateTime: String?


init?(JSON: [String: AnyObject]) {

    guard let eventID = JSON["event_id"] as? String,
        let eventName = JSON["event_name"] as? String,
        let eventLocation = JSON["event_location"] as? String,
        let startDateTime = JSON["start_datetime"] as? String,
        let endDateTime = JSON["end_datetime"] as? String,
        let participantCount = JSON["participant_count"] as? Int else {

            return nil
    }

    self.id = eventID
    self.name = eventName
    self.location = eventLocation
    self.endDateTime = endDateTime
    self.participantCount = participantCount

    if let formattedStartDateTime = getDateFromString(dateString: startDateTime, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") {
        self.startDateTime = formattedStartDateTime
    }else {
        self.startDateTime = Date()
    }

    if let deleteFlag = JSON["delete_flag"] as? Bool {
        self.deleteFlag = deleteFlag
    }else {
        self.deleteFlag = nil
    }

    if let deletedDateTime = JSON["deleted_datetime"] as? String {
        self.deleteDateTime = deletedDateTime
    }else {
        self.deleteDateTime = nil
    }

    if let dateCreated = JSON["date_created"] as? String {
        self.dateCreated = dateCreated
    }else {
        self.dateCreated = nil
    }

    if let hasRaffle = JSON["hasRaffle"] as? Bool {
        self.hasRaffle = hasRaffle
    }else {
        self.hasRaffle = nil
    }

    if let registrationReq = JSON["registration_req"] as? Bool {
        self.registrationReq = registrationReq
    }else {
        self.registrationReq = nil
    }

    if let closedFlag = JSON["closed_flag"] as? Bool {
        self.closedFlag = closedFlag
    }else {
        self.closedFlag = nil
    }

    if let closedDateTime = JSON["closed_datetime"] as? String {
        self.closedDateTime = closedDateTime
    }else {
        self.closedDateTime = nil
    }

    if let reopenFlag = JSON["reopen_flag"] as? Bool {
        self.reopenFlag = reopenFlag
    }else {
        self.reopenFlag = nil
    }

    if let reopenDateTime = JSON["reopen_datetime"] as? String {
        self.reopenDateTime = reopenDateTime
    }else {
        self.reopenDateTime = nil
    }

}
```

}

**APIService**

```
 class APIService
 {
    let eventAPIKey: String
    let eventBaseURL: URL?

    //static let kEventID = "id"
   init(APIKey: String)
  {
   self.eventAPIKey = APIKey
   eventBaseURL = URL(string: BASE_URL)
   }

   func validatePasscode(passcode: String, completion: @escaping     (Event?) -> Void)
 {
   let passcodeURL = URL (string: "\(PASSCODE_CHECKER_URL)/\(passcode)")


    Alamofire.request(passcodeURL!, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

      switch response.result{
        case .success:

                if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value{
                        print(passcodeJSON)
                    completion(Event(JSON: json as [String : Any]))
                    }

      case .failure(let error):
           print("\(error)")
        }

     }

     }


 }
```

Comment: No need for your struct to conform to Codable if you are not going to use any of the built-in Swift 4 encoding/decoding.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks I tried what you suggested but unfortunately _Thread 1: signal SIGABRT_ appeared in line _completion(Event(JSON: json as! [String : AnyObject]))_ it shows **Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x110df0608) to 'NSDictionary' (0x110df1288).** How can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to try and initialize the `Event` struct with the data you received `passcodeJSON`. As you can see your `Event` initializer is `init?(JSON: [String: AnyObject])`

```
if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value{
   // print(passcodeJSON)
   completion(Event(JSON: passcodeJSON))
}
```

and where you call your API service:

```
apiServiceClient.validatePasscode(passcode: "testing") { eventDetails in 
   // do something with eventDetails here
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion, I tried to do what you suggested. _Thread 1: signal SIGABRT_ , appeared in line _completion(Event(JSON: json as! [String : AnyObject]))_ when I build the app. How can I fix it? thank you

Comment: Can you post the output or a part of it? It must be crashing since the data type you are casting doesn’t match [String: AnyObject]